# Submitting Forms through HTML Service with Apps Script not working on 1 of 2 forms

Tags: google-apps-script, html

**Preface:**
I've created a G-Suite spreadsheet which is to be used as an order form for my customers. I am attempting a "Basic" web app by creating HTML pages for as much of the user input as possible using Google's Apps Script.
I'm doing it in hopes of being able to eliminate the need to open the actual spreadsheet itself at some point in favor of a web app. And for learning various things in small doses so to speak along the way.

Right now I have images served from Google Storage and input into the Spreadsheet cells using a URL. Works great. I have product data being imported from different "Supplier" spreadsheets (1 per supplier) with my customer info on another "Customer Details" spreadsheet.
With the next step being the recording of orders sent to another "Orders" spreadsheet dealing with the order process.   Much of the code is taken from Google's developer examples, and I'm taking the trouble to implement Materialize in hopes of using this as a web app at some point.

---

**Question:**
I currently have a function being called during the opening of the spreadsheet which presents a dialog with a form element `userForm` simply asking for the user's email.

I plan to look up that email against the "Customer Details" spreadsheet and return the information I already have there so they can confirm shipping details are correct. If they are a new customer (email not found)  it will present a different HTML dialog with a form element `myForm` asking for said details.  the myForm dialog submits info and works perfectly. the simpler userForm does not.  When the Submit button is clicked the dialog goes blank but nothing else happens.
In the execution details, it doesn't show anything more than it successfully created the dialog. there's simply nothing to go on with regards to what has happened after the click event of the submit button.
I've tried all kinds of combinations and had it show failure once ( which is where I have left it) it only showed anything in the logs that one time.

I'm quite frankly stumped and in search of guidance as to how I might solve this needless to say I have no formal training so my understanding of the language is lacking in terms the various scopes and rules which I'm sure are at play here.

Here is the **non-functional** dialog code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css">

   <style>
          main {top: 70px;bottom: 60px;width: 100%} 
          body{margin:5;width:100%;height:100%;overflow-x:hidden}footer,header{position:fixed;width:100%}header{top:0}footer{bottom:0}main{position:absolute;border-top:2px solid #F2F2F2;border-bottom:2px solid #F2F2F2;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden}
           /* label color */
           input label {
           color: #37474f;}/* label focus color */
           input[type=text]:focus + label {
           color: #ffeb3b;}
         /* label underline focus color */
           .input-field input[type=text]:focus {
           border-bottom: 1px solid #ffeb3b;
           box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;}
         /* valid color */
           .input-field input[type=text]:valid {
           border-bottom: 1px solid #c6a700;
           box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;}
         /* invalid color */
           .input-field input[type=text]:invalid {
           border-bottom: 1px solid #ffff6b;
           box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;}
         /* icon prefix focus color */
           .input-field .prefix.active {
           color: #fdd835;}
           /* submit button */
           btn {
           background: #37474f;}
           btn:focus {
           background: #ffeb3b;}

    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 
    <script>     
        $(document).ready(function() {
         Materialize.updateTextFields();
       });
        function formSubmit(userObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateScreen()).processUser(userObject);`
        }
        function updateScreen(){
        google.script.host.close();
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:10px">
      <div class="row">
        <form id="userForm" onsubmit="formSubmit(this)" class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s10">
              <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
                <input id="userEmail" name="userEmail" type="text">
              <label for="userEmail">Email</label>
            </div>
           </div>
         <button class="btn waves-effect waves-yellow" type="submit" value="submit" onClick="formSubmit(this)">Submit<i class="material-icons right">send</i></button> 
       </form>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the **functional** dialog

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      main {top: 70px;bottom: 60px;width: 100%;} 
      body{margin:5;width:100%;height:100%;overflow-x:hidden}footer,header{position:fixed;width:100%}header{top:0}footer{bottom:0}main{position:absolute;border-top:2px solid #F2F2F2;border-bottom:2px solid #F2F2F2;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden;}
             input label {
           color: #37474f;}/* label focus color */
           input[type=text]:focus + label {
           color: #ffeb3b;}
         /* label underline focus color */
           .input-field input[type=text]:focus {
           border-bottom: 1px solid #ffeb3b;
           box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;}
         /* valid color */
           .input-field input[type=text]:valid {
           border-bottom: 1px solid #c6a700;
           box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;}
         /* invalid color */
           .input-field input[type=text]:invalid {
           border-bottom: 1px solid #ffff6b;
           box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;}
         /* icon prefix focus color */
           .input-field .prefix.active {
           color: #fdd835;}
    </style>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('select').material_select();  
    });
    function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    });
    }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

    function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().processForm(formObject);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
    <div class="container center-align" style="margin:5px">
      <div class="row">
        <h4 class="col s12">Wholsale order sheet</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
   <main>  
     <div class="container" style="margin-top:10px">
       <div class="row">
         <form name="myForm"  onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)"  class="col s12">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="input-field col s6">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">store</i>
                 <input id="argCompName" name="argCompName" type="text">
               <label for="argCompName">Company Name</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">account_box</i>
                 <input id="argFirstName" name="argFirstName" type="text">
               <label for="argFirstName">First Name</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">account_box</i>
                 <input id="argLastName" name="argLastName" type="text">
               <label for="argLastName">Last Name</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
                 <input id="argEmail" name="argEmail" type="text">
               <label for="argEmail">Email</label>
             </div>
              <div class="input-field col s6">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                 <input id="argPhone" name="argPhone" type="text">
               <label for="argPhone">Phone</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">location_on</i>
                 <input id="argAddress1" name="argAddress1" type="text">
               <label for="argAddress1">Address 1</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">location_on</i>
                 <input id="argAddress2" name="argAddress2" type="text">
               <label for="argAddress2">Address 2</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">location_city</i>
                 <input id="argCity" name="argCity" type="text">
               <label for="argCity">City</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">
             <select id="argProvince" name="argProvince">
             <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
             <option value="1">ON</option>
             <option value="2">NF</option>
             <option value="3">NU</option>
             <option value="4">NT</option>
             <option value="5">NB</option>
             <option value="6">NS</option>
             <option value="7">YT</option>
             <option value="8">SK</option>
             <option value="9">PE</option>
             <option value="10">BC</option>
             <option value="11">AB</option>
             <option value="12">MB</option>
             <option value="13">QC</option>
             </select>
             <label>Province</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">location_on</i>
                 <input id="argPostalCode" name="argPostalCode" type="text">
               <label for="argPostalCode">Postal Code</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">explore</i>
                 <input id="argCountry" name="argCountry" type="text">
               <label for="argCountry">Country</label>
              </div>
             <button class="btn waves-effect waves-yellow" style="background:#37474f" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit<i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
           </div>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
   </main> 
    <footer>
      <div class="container center-align" style="margin-top:10px">
        <p style="margin"> Prefer a website interface for ordering? Check out </p> <a href="https://zeerosmoke.com">Zeerosmoke.com</a>
      </div>
    </footer> 
  </body>
</html>
```

the related functions  are:

```
function openForm() {
    Logger.log('openForm ran!');
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setWidth(900).setHeight(600);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Please enter your contact info");
    return;
    }

  function openLogin() {
    Logger.log('open Login Called!');
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); //to be used in future to prefill the value attribute
       Logger.log(user);
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('openDialog').setWidth(300).setHeight(600);

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Please enter your email address");
    };

 function processUser(userObject) {
   Logger.log("processUser has been called");
   var s = SpreadsheetApp().openById("1rkeoMHv8TErN5y7Jnh8UBvZ7H8fKjA61yPrjcbLvOE0").getSheetByName("CustomerIndex");
   var dataRange = s.getRange(2,2,s.getLastRow(),s.getLastColumn());
   var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
   var user = userObject.userEmail();
   for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    Logger.log("User Email"+ user);
    var row = data[i];
    var company = row[0];
    var first = row[1];
    var last = row[2];
    var email = row[3];
    var phone = row[4];
    var addy1 = row[6];
    var addy2 = row[7];
    var city = row[8];
    var prov = row[9];
    var postal = row[10];
    var country = row[11]; 
      if (user === email){ 
      var compNameRange = MAIN.getRange(4,3);
      var contactFirstN = MAIN.getRange(4,7);
      var contacLastN = MAIN.getRange(5,7);
      var emailRange = MAIN.getRange(7,7);
      var phoneRange = MAIN.getRange(6,7);
      var address1Range = MAIN.getRange(5,3);
      var address2Range = MAIN.getRange(6,3);
      var cityRange = MAIN.getRange(7,3);
      var provinceRange = MAIN.getRange(8,5);
      var postalCodeRange = MAIN.getRange(9,3);
      var countryRange = MAIN.getRange(10,3); 
       Logger.log("user submit: " + company);
      if(company !=""){
        compNameRange.setValue(company)};
      if(formFirstN !=""){
        contactFirstN.setValue(first)};  
      if(formLastN !=""){
        contacLastN.setValue(last)};
      if(formEmail !=""){
        emailRange.setValue(email)};
      if(formPhone !=""){
        phoneRange.setValue(phone)};
      if(formAddress1 !=""){
        address1Range.setValue(addy1)};
      if(formAddress2 !=""){
        address2Range.setValue(addy2)};
      if(formCity !=""){
        cityRange.setValue(city)};
      if(formProvince !=""){
        provinceRange.setValue(prov)};
      if(formCode !=""){
        postalCodeRange.setValue(postal)};
      if(formCountry !=""){
        countryRange.setValue(country)};
          }
      else{
      openForm()};
    };
  };

function processForm(formObject) {
  var formCompName = formObject.argCompName;
  var formFirstN = formObject.argFirstName;
  var formLastN= formObject.argLastName;
  var formEmail = formObject.argEmail;
  var formPhone = formObject.argPhone;
  var formAddress1 = formObject.argAddress1;
  var formAddress2 = formObject.argAddress2;
  var formCity = formObject.argCity;
  var formProvince = formObject.argProvince;
  var formCode = formObject.argPostalCode;
  var formCountry = formObject.argCountry;
  var compNameRange = MAIN.getRange(4,3);
  var contactFirstN = MAIN.getRange(4,7);
  var contacLastN = MAIN.getRange(5,7);
  var emailRange = MAIN.getRange(7,7);
  var phoneRange = MAIN.getRange(6,7);
  var address1Range = MAIN.getRange(5,3);
  var address2Range = MAIN.getRange(6,3);
  var cityRange = MAIN.getRange(7,3);
  var provinceRange = MAIN.getRange(8,5);
  var postalCodeRange = MAIN.getRange(9,3);
  var countryRange = MAIN.getRange(10,3); 
   Logger.log("formCompName: " + formCompName);
  if(formCompName !=""){
    compNameRange.setValue(formCompName)};
  if(formFirstN !=""){
    contactFirstN.setValue(formFirstN)};  
  if(formLastN !=""){
    contacLastN.setValue(formLastN)};
  if(formEmail !=""){
    emailRange.setValue(formEmail)};
  if(formPhone !=""){
    phoneRange.setValue(formPhone)};
  if(formAddress1 !=""){
    address1Range.setValue(formAddress1)};
  if(formAddress2 !=""){
    address2Range.setValue(formAddress2)};
  if(formCity !=""){
    cityRange.setValue(formCity)};
  if(formProvince !=""){
    provinceRange.setValue(formProvince)};
  if(formCode !=""){
    postalCodeRange.setValue(formCode)};
  if(formCountry !=""){
    countryRange.setValue(formCountry)};

};
```

Since, for  the time being, I'm only asking for publicly available data i have not attempted an OAuth type login but it's in the plan. Right now I simply need to understand why one form submits answers and the other does not even show up in the logs. I hope I've been clear enough and provided the correct amount of information. I can't share the spreadsheet publicly unfortunately. 
Thank you for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, ..... there was a back tick   `   at  the end of the script runner I'll leave it there for you to find as it's a stupid annoying definition of the word BUG!